# Finding centroid of point pairs based on common ID using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve

I want to take a series of point pairs within a single shapefile and find a single centroid point for each pair.

For example in the image below, I would like there to be one point "31", one point "32", etc. without having to create a new point one by one.

[image: example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) the file based on the `id` field (or whatever field your numbers are in). This will create a layer with multipart point features. Then calculate the centroids ([Mean Centers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Mean_Center/005p00000018000000/)) of the new multipart layer.